Is it possible to start a Dijkstra search from a source node s, bounded at r, with a non-empty distance map and priority queue?
TL:DR: I want to know whether correctness is affected if I start Dijkstra with a distances map that already contains shortest paths shorter than $r$ and a priority queue initialised with those elements.

I am implementing a complex shortest path algorithm for large graphs (in C++ but this question is not about the implementation).
This algorithm basically constructs a hierarchy of shortcut graphs by utilizing nice properties.
The first step in the algorithm to construct a shortcut graph $G[i]$ is to determine its vertex set $C[i]$. I have no problem with this. The second step involves adding edges to the shortcut graph by following certain rules:
there is an edge between a pair of nodes $u,v \in C[i]$ iff the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ in the original graph $G$ does not contain a node $w \in C[i], w\neq u, w\neq v$ and if its length is no more than $r$.
At each level $i$ of the hierarchy, the bound $r$ is equal to $8^i$. To compute the shortest paths between all node pairs $u,v \in C[i]$, I simply use Dijkstra bounded at $r$, which works successfully. Initially, I thought that it would be nice to save the results from a level $i$'s Dijkstra search in order to start the search at the next level with existing information.
Due to the fact that the graphs are huge and that the distances map computed by this Dijkstra contains $\{(v: (d_G(u,v))) | v \in G, d_G(u,v) \leq 8^i\}$ (and each value in this map actually contains a bit more than just the distance, for other requirements of my algorithm), I assumed that it would be pointless and unreasonable in terms of memory to try and keep the returned value of Dijkstra and pass it to the next level.
But after thinking about it again and given that the distances map contains:

32-bit int for keys (reached nodes)
64-bit double for the distances, which I realise now that I could probably reduce to floats
64-bit double for another distance measure useful for my algorithm
32-bit parent to be able to find the path between the source and this node using the map

I realise that for graphs of e.g. 10M nodes, this is  228MB, which is considerable but definitely manageable, given that I don't need to store them after the next shortcut graph is complete. So I want to try and see if it works.
So my question is:
I am now thinking about initializing level $i$'s Dijkstra search with a distances map $D = \{v:(d_G(u,v), ...)|v\in G, d_G(u,v) <= 8^{i-1})\}$ and a priority queue that contains $\{(d_G(u,v), v)|v\in D\}$. Are there any correctness issues that a normally initialized Dijkstra would not have to worry about ?
In my understanding, the search wouldn't push any element to the queue until it reaches the end of the search space of the previous search, and then it would simply "resume" normally.
I am just not sure if this is correct, or if it breaks the correctness of Dijkstra's algorithm in certain cases.
I have tried on small hand-made input graphs that I could manually run the algorithm on, but I am not confident enough to affirm that it works on all graphs (by all graphs, I mean those that a regular Dijkstra could work on, of course).
